# the game is not recognized by game center

Tags: iphone, authentication, game-center

Hi
I am trying to add game center to my iphone app.
I have done the following steps

1) I have added an app to my itnuesAccount
2) I assigned the Bundle ID as net.myCompany.myGameCenter
3) I am using the same "net.myCompany.myGameCenter" as Bundle identifier in my info.plist
4) using the [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html.) provided by apple i added the authentication steps.

```
self.currentLeaderBoard= kEasyLeaderboardID;

 self.currentScore= 0;

 [super viewDidLoad];
 if([GameCenterManager isGameCenterAvailable])
 {
  self.gameCenterManager= [[[GameCenterManager alloc] init] autorelease];
  [self.gameCenterManager setDelegate: self];
  [self.gameCenterManager authenticateLocalUser];

  [self updateCurrentScore];
 }
 else
 {
  [self showAlertWithTitle: @"Game Center Support Required!"
       message: @"The current device does not support Game Center, which this sample requires."];
 }
```

I have tried putting the kEasyLeaderboardID value equal to the one that i placed myself upon creating the new leader board.
I tried the other one, that i defined at step2. "myComap"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah my bad
the BundleId at the iTunes connect and the one in the info.plist have to be same 
and the leaderboardID is used for for submitting and viewing the score.

Comment: This worked just fine! To find the bundle ID in ITunes Connect, go to the app details, click on More and then About this App.

Answer (score 11):

Other people who are stuck with this problem to this date, like me..

Turned out because my devices were jailbroken =/ .. I read an answer somewhere on stackoverflow.com that jailbroken devices interpret the app as a "real-world" app, thus not discovering sandbox accounts ..

I restored my iPad, and got an iPod touch from a friend, and both worked painlessly .. (previously, I tried it on 3 jailbroken devices, for which none of them worked ..).

Comment: is there a way to use sandbox mode on a jailbroken device?

Answer (score 2):

Many reasons are there for this problem

Add your app on itunesconnect.apple.com

Fill all information (Make Sure your available/publish date)

Can enter dummy data, but bundle id and name must be original as your real game.(Can't change)

then put your leaderboard/Achivement id  in your app.

If still you getting same message "Game Center is not recognized this game", check your availability date which you have enter while filling the information of your app on itunesconnect.apple.com. This date should not be after your current date.

If again you are getting same problem then upload this app on AppStore. (After checking you can reject this uploaded binary)

Comment: I had some problems with this. I strongly suspect that it was creating a single leaderboard entry that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried every tips but still got this warning!!

Finally, I solved it by creating a new App on [**iTunes Connect**](https://itunesconnect.apple.com)!! After you've added a new App for your project, you need to press ***"Manage Game Center"*** and choose a group. Then your game will be recognized by the game center, even you haven't added 'Leaderboards' or 'Achievements'.

Answer (score 1):

Gah!  This was driving me crazy.  I had done everything right, had all the correct bundleIDs, certificates, etc., my app is already in the app store, but I was still getting this message.  (iOS9.x, XCode 7.1)

Turns out that adding a single achievement in iTunesConnect made things work.  I suspect I could have added a leaderboard, instead.

Basically, the message can also mean "while your app says it's Game Center capable, it doesn't actually have any GC content" and adding an achievement or leaderboard makes the game "recognized" by GC.

Answer (score 0):

Seems on iOS 8 GameCenter sandbox is disabled by default. I met a similar problem and solved by enabling Game Center sandbox in Settings and re-logining.