# Game not recognized in Game Center

Tags: ios, center, gamekit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [the game is not recognized by game center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781794/the-game-is-not-recognized-by-game-center)

I know this has been asked a couple times, but the solutions in other threads, such as deleting the app from Simulator and reinstalling weren't working for me.

The bundle ID in my info.plist matches the ID in iTunes Connect and I have properly setup a test application in ITC to work with.

The only way I have gotten of this alert is by setting gamekit as requirement in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key of the info.plist. According to Apple's docs, this should only be set if GameKit is a requirement for the app to run and is not required to integrate with Game Center.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says game is not recognized by game center means your game center code is working!! Good..

Sign out of your game center account on the device.. close the game center app completely.. close your own app completely.. Including in background.. Open the app again.. It should prompt you to sign into game center..

I think it is caused by your account is a live account and in order to log into your game, it needs to be in sandbox mode..

Comment: Yep, that worked! I misread the GameKit documentation and had logged in through the GameCenter app first instead of logging in through my own app.